# Is there an equivalent to type traits from C++ in other languages?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I like the concept of type traits, because it solves some design questions in a clear and extensible way. For example, imagine we have a couple of printer classes and document classes.

Since new document types may be added later, the printer should not directly know which document it is printing, so that it doesn't  have to be adjusted then. On the other hand, documents shouldn't know about all printers.

By providing traits about how to print documents, this is the only place that must be modified when adding new documents. Moreover, if there are new printers, they can use the same traits directly and focus on the internal printing process that differs from the other printers.

```
// Documents
class pdf { /* ... */ };
class txt { /* ... */ };

// Traits
template<typename t>
struct traits; // No default trait, so new documents throw compilation error

template<>
struct traits<pdf> {
    static std::string get_title(pdf& document) { /* ... */ }
    static std::string get_content(pdf& document) { /* ... */ }
    static bool has_images = true;
};

template<>
struct traits<txt> {
    static std::string get_title(txt& document) { return ""; } // Not supported
    static std::string get_content(txt& document) { /* ... */ }
    static bool has_images = false;
};

// Printers
class canon_printer : public printer {
    template<typename T>
    void print(T document) override
    {
        std::string title = traits<T>.get_title(document);
        // ...
        if (traits<T>.has_images)
            // ...
    }
};
```

To me, it looks quite powerful. As of now, I have only seen this concept in C++. Is there a similar concept in other programming languages? I'm more looking for a language independent term for this approach rather than a list of languages.

Comment: In e.g. Java or C#, Document and Printer would be an interface or abstract class so they could vary independently - is that the sort of answer you're looking for ?

Comment: I don't know any languages that have something like C++ templates with specialization, but then again, it seems like one would need to be able to enumerate *all* languages in order to answer this question.

Comment: Traits (at least like these) basically implement the strategy pattern, but with compile time rather than run time resolution.  The strategy pattern can be implemented in pretty much any language which supports OO.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm more looking for a language independent term for this approach. Let me add this to the question.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thank you, that's kind of what I was looking for. Could you make an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're using the traits for.  For many uses, some
form of the strategy pattern would be an appropriate solution.  You'll
get run time resolution, rather than compile time, and you can't really
use it to define types, however.

In your example, I'm not sure that you want traits even in C++.  Your
function `Printer::print` is apparently virtual (since you override it
in a derived class), but is also a template; this is not legal in C++.
What you probably need is some variant of the bridge pattern, using
virtual functions even in C++.  You might, for example, have an abstract
base class along the lines of:

```
class DocumentInformation
{
public:
    virtual ~DocumentInformation() = default;
    virtual std::string get_title() const = 0;
    virtual std::string get_content() const = 0;
    //  ...
    virtual bool has_images() const = 0;
};
```

Then for each document type, you derive a concrete instance:

```
class PDFDocumentInformation : public DocumentInformation
{
    PDFDocument const& myDocument;
public:
    PDFDocumentInformation( PDFDocument const& document )
        : myDocument( document )
    {
    }
    std::string get_title() const override
    {
        //  ...
    }
    // ...
    bool has_images() const override { return true; }
};
```

You're (virtual) `Printer::print` function then takes a 
`DocumentInformation const&`, and uses it to obtain the information it
needs.

Depending on the way your code is organized, you might not even need the
bridge.  It's often possible to have all of your concrete document
classes derived directly from an abstract `Document`, with the virtual
functions, and pass this to `Printer::print`.  This is, in fact, the
usual case; the bridge is only needed if you have existing document
classes with incompatible interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, also for showing me the mistake in my example.